# Apply style to an element as if it were in a different location in the DOM

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working on a system which moves an element to the near top of the DOM (makes an element a child of `<body>`). One of the problems with my setup is that CSS child selectors stop working, because the element now has a different parent.

```html
<!-- the <p> was moved in the dom, and the placeholder div keeps its spot -->

<body>
    <p>I was styled, but now I'm not :(</p>

    <div class="mydiv">
        <div class="placeholder"></div>
    </div>
</body>

<style>
    .mydiv * {
        background-color: #ccc;
    }
</style>
```

[This REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/598fb3ccc4a3496ea7636960780326f0?version=4.2.12) contains a larger example that includes some DOM movement code.

Is there a way, using Javascript, to keep, (or make it appear to keep) the styling of the element, even while it's in a different position in the DOM? (do note that the element and styles aren't known ahead of time, refactoring the CSS isn't an option)

Comment: You can either select it by knowing how many `<p>` tags exist above it within `<body>`, and using `p:nth-of-type(n)` within `body` Or you could give it a Class or an ID?

Comment: "I am working on a system with a piece that pops a node out" ... clarification needed. Try using standard terminology.

Comment: Or use the universal language and prepare a sketch/mock up of what you desire. Attached to your question.

Comment: @GetSet I don't know if the mechanics of how the node is moved are relevant to the question, I could prepare a little mock up though

Comment: Was just asking that you illustrate your desired result.

Comment: The only thing in your current css is on background color. Where is what that you are trying to position? Hence a picture is a thousand words.

Comment: @GetSet I added a repl, I'm counting on you..........

Comment: I suppose that you don't have access to the CSS by saying "The system is generic, so using a different style setup isn't an option", but do you have access to the JS?

Comment: @Pøziel OP has style tags in his code. So CSS access is not the issue rather the terminology he has adopted is hiding the problem, whatever that may be.

Comment: @GetSet Is the question more clear now?

Comment: No, there is no easy option to achieve this. The only thing I can think of is to use `getComputedStyles` on each of the elements, then check which properties are non-default, and apply those via inline styles at the moved position. Please note that this is a really expensive operation if you're moving alot of nodes.

Comment: Please include all relevant code **in the question itself**, just like it says in [ask].

Comment: @HereticMonkey the dom manipulation isn't relevant to the question, which is why it's not included

Comment: Your code manipulates the DOM, and you want this theoretical code to apply after that DOM manipulation has occurred. Not on a static document that has the DOM in the same configuration as the manipulated document, but on the manipulated document. To me, the DOM manipulation is central to the question, not just relevant.